# Visual studio Windows app deploy is stuck

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, windows

I am using VS Express 2013.

When I am running an app for the first time then it is working. Second time onwards when I run it, it is getting stuck after it shows the following line.

```
 1>------ Deploy started: Project: App2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

If I stop the build at that point, VS is crashing.

Sometime if I unistall the app and then run it again then it starts working again. Sometimes even that also is not working. Only option then is t restart the system.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Is this happening in the emulator or a windows phone?  If it is a phone how many apps that you are debugging do you have on the device?

Comment: I am running it on Windows 8 and selecting the option Local Machine

Comment: Really annoying - happens several times a day ...

Comment: @TheEye : Yes it is. I later switched to professional full version and it never crashes. 

If you are using express version, try to repair your VS. Sometimes that worked for me.

Comment: I'm on VS Professional unfortunately ... already reinstalled twice because of other problems, don't really want to do it again